# TextView in SliderView text shown and text value bug [the n'th TextView is returning its initialized value after changing (n+2)'th textView]

Tags: java, android, debugging, textview, android-viewpager

i have a textView in SliderView like this

activitity_slider.xml

```
 <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/slideViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

slide_layout.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    android:background="@color/white">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/HareketEkranı"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/hareket"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/HareketResmi"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:contentDescription="Hareket"/>
                //android:src="@drawable/ic_armcircle"
            <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
                android:id="@+id/haraketdatasi"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="Hareket"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/darkTextColor"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/HareketAdi"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:textAlignment="gravity"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:text="Armcircle"
                        android:textColor="@color/red"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TekrarYazisiSlide"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:text="Tekrar"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/darkTextColor"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TekrarSayisiSlide"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                        android:text="TekrarSayisi"
                        android:textAlignment="gravity"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/red"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/kesme"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                    android:text="/"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TekrarhedefiSlide"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                        android:text="25"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE !**

SliderAdapter.java

```
    package gymholix.assistx;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;

public class SliderAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public SliderAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    //Arrays
    public int[] slide_images = {
            R.drawable.ic_armcircle,
            R.drawable.ic_ropejump,
            R.drawable.ic_jumpingjack,
            R.drawable.ic_burpee,
            R.drawable.ic_squat
    };
    public String[] slide_headings = {
            "ArmCircle",
        "RopeJump",
        "JumpingJack",
        "Burpee",
        "Squat"
};
/*public String[] tekrar_sayisi = {
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0"*/
public int[] tekrar_sayisi = {
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5
};



@Override
public int getCount() {
    return slide_headings.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return view == (RelativeLayout) object;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view =layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_layout, container, false);

    ImageView slideImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.HareketResmi);
    TextView slideHeading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.HareketAdi);
    TextView slideTekraSayisi = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TekrarSayisiSlide);

    slideImageView.setImageResource((slide_images[position]));
    slideHeading.setText(slide_headings[position]);
    slideTekraSayisi.setText(String.valueOf(tekrar_sayisi[position]));



    container.addView(view);

    return view;
}

@Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {

    }

}
```

Slider.Java

```
    package gymholix.assistx;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Slider extends AppCompatActivity {


    private LinearLayout mDotLayout;
    private String asd;
    private int asdf;

    TextView DenemeSayiCek;
    int position;
    View view;
    int count;
    View viewFix;
    Context context;
    //Sensors---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private Accelerometer accelerometer;
    private Gyroscope gyroscope;

    public double[] acc={3.00,2.00,1.00};
    public double[] gyr={3.00,2.00,1.00};

    //Sensors---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Main------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Antreman antreman = new Antreman();
        context = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_slider);

        ViewPager AktifHareket = findViewById(R.id.slideViewPager);
        mDotLayout = findViewById(R.id.dotsLayout);
        SliderAdapter sliderAdapter = new SliderAdapter(this);
        AktifHareket.setAdapter((sliderAdapter));

        addDotsIndicator();

        //Saydir Buton------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        TextView Deneme = findViewById(R.id.deneme);
        TextView Deneme4 = findViewById(R.id.deneme4);
    

    TextView Deneme3 = findViewById(R.id.deneme3);
            TextView Deneme2 = findViewById(R.id.deneme2);
            Button Saydir = findViewById(R.id.SaydirSlide);
            Button Saydir2 = findViewById(R.id.Saydir2Slide);
            Saydir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                position = AktifHareket.getCurrentItem();
                view = AktifHareket.getChildAt(position);
                count = AktifHareket.indexOfChild(view);
                viewFix = AktifHareket.getChildAt(count);
                DenemeSayiCek = viewFix.findViewById(R.id.TekrarSayisiSlide);
                asd = DenemeSayiCek.getText().toString();
                asdf = Integer.parseInt(asd);
                asdf++;
                DenemeSayiCek.setText(String.valueOf(asdf));
                Deneme.setText(String.valueOf(asd));
                Deneme2.setText(String.valueOf(position));
                Deneme3.setText(String.valueOf(asdf));
                Deneme4.setText(String.valueOf(SliderAdapter.POSITION_NONE));

            }
        });

        //Saydir Buton------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //ImageButton-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ImageView logoImage = findViewById(R.id.logo);
        logoImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                antreman.AntremanSayfasi(context);
            }
        });
        antreman.AntremanSayfasi(context);//Açılışta Sayfayı açsın diye
        //ImageButton-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //Sensors-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        accelerometer = new Accelerometer(this);
        gyroscope = new Gyroscope(this);
        accelerometer.setListner(new Accelerometer.Listner() {
            @Override
            public void onTranslation(float ax, float ay, float az) {
                setAccValue(ax, ay, az);
                Antreman.GetSensorValues.OnAccelerometerChangeValues = acc;
            }
        });
        gyroscope.setListner(new Gyroscope.Listner() {
            @Override
            public void onRotation(float gx, float gy, float gz) {
                setGyroValue(gx, gy, gz);
                Antreman.GetSensorValues.OnGyroscopeChangeValues = gyr;
                //OnSensorChangeValues.add(1, String.valueOf(gyr) );
            }
        });
/*        Saydir2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });*/
        //Sensors-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }
    //Sensors---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        accelerometer.register();
        gyroscope.register();
    }
    protected void onPouse(){
        super.onPause();
        accelerometer.unregister();
        gyroscope.unregister();
    }
    //Sensors---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //SensorsValueGetAndSet-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public double[] setAccValue(float ac, float bc, float cc){
        this.acc[0] = ac;
        this.acc[1] = bc;
        this.acc[2] = cc;
        return acc;
    }
    public double[] setGyroValue(float qq, float wq, float eq){
        this.gyr[0] = qq;
        this.gyr[1] = wq;
        this.gyr[2] = eq;
        return gyr;
    }
    public void getAccValue(float ac, float bc, float cc){
        ac = (float) acc[0];
        bc = (float) acc[1];
        cc = (float) acc[2];
    }
    public void getGyroValue(float qq, float wq, float eq){
        qq = (float) gyr[0];
        wq = (float) gyr[1];
        eq = (float) gyr[2];
    }
    //SensorsValueGetAndSet-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void addDotsIndicator(){
        TextView[] mDots = new TextView[3];
        for(int i = 0; i < mDots.length; i++){
            mDots[i] = new TextView(this);
            mDots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
            mDots[i].setTextSize(35);
            mDots[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
            mDotLayout.addView(mDots[i]);
        }
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

the weird thing about this code is; while running the button changes the text value correctly in the first pager, and the seckond one but when it comes the third one while it changes the value it resets the first pagers shown value but the getText() method inherits the correct value but the text is frozen and it cant be changed any more, after that the other page's values cant be changed either, but the getText() method still works fine and gets the correct value.

any idea will speed up my debuging process thanx anyway...

Comment: can you provide complete code of adapter and how you are calling it in your activity

Comment: Have you tried setOffscreenPageLimit (int limit) https://stackoverflow.com/a/12706211/9502601

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding this snipped solved the problem, it is a must to define borders to the pager

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
    int size = sliderAdapter.slide_headings.length;
    AktifHareket.setOffscreenPageLimit(size);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: i changed the ansver